# Efficiently Filtering Large Sets of Multi-Key Objects

Tags: c#

I have a number of items, each of which has a number of Codes associated with it.  Each item will have a collection of these.

```
List<ComplexObject> myCollection = new List<ComplexObject>();
var item = new ComplexObject() 
           { 
               Id = 5, 
               Codes = new List<string>() { "1", "4", "5" } 
           }; 
myCollection.Add(item);
```

I need to filter these objects by code, on demand.  There will be many entries, potentially >1,000,000, each containing a collection of associated keys.

I can obviously use something like:

```
var output = (from p in myCollection
             from q in p.Codes
             where q == x
             select p).ToList();
```

But, I want to be able to filter by code without having to loop through all objects - which is what is going on here.  Performance is critical in this context, so I want to achieve a better than O(n) lookup time on these objects.

I've considered creating a dictionary that has each Code as a key, and a collection of ComplexObjectIds, but this seems a bit clunky - but perhaps it's the best option. In my head I envision some kind of web network collection...

Given that performance is my ultimate goal, is there a more optimal approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So create an [`ILookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534291%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) using the [`.ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549211%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method:

```
var lookup = myCollection
  .SelectMany(co => co.Codes.Select(code => new{code, co}))
  .ToLookup(x => x.code, x => x.co);
```

so now you can query the lookup

```
IEnumerable<ComplexObject> complexObjs = lookup["1"];
```

in O(1) time.

Comment: That's great.  When adding new entries, this call will need to be refreshed, correct?

Comment: Indeed... if it's a live collection, you might be better off maintaining an `IDictionary<string, IList<ComplexObject>>` instead. Performance-wise, for lookups, they'll be approximately equivalent.

Comment: Or if you need to remove items too, an `IDictionary<string, HashSet<ComplexObject>>` might give better performance yet if you expect lots of entries per key, but you'd need to implement a sensible `GetHashCode` and equality members for you `ComplexObject` class.